# PSD Template to Visual Studio/ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, templates, photoshop

I have recently designed a template in Photoshop and I would like to know what is the best way to import my template to Visual Studio? Is it through slicing the template in Photoshop and using the html codes in my Master Page on VS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will probably work just fine, but it's not a technique the pros would use. Here is an alternative approach that will likely yield better results, and avoid some of the frustrations of Photoshop along the way:

http://24ways.org/2009/make-your-mockup-in-markup

Comment: +1 for the right thing to do. One cannot be farther from reality when they use photoshop for mockups!